# Как удалить элементы tooltip

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как удалять такие элементы:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TOOLINFO ti = {};
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = window;
    ti.hinst = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ti.uId = i;
    ti.lpszText = bufferWeight;
    ti.rect.left = rect.left;
    ti.rect.top = rect.top;
    ti.rect.right = rect.right;
    ti.rect.bottom = rect.bottom;
    SendMessage(tooltip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTOOLINFO)&ti);
}
```

Пытался удалить примерно так, но не удаляет:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TOOLINFO ti = {};
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = window;
    ti.hinst = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    ti.uId = i;
    SendMessage(tooltip, TTM_DELTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTOOLINFO)&ti);
}
```

Comment: Какие проблемы возникают с обращением к документации на сайте Майкрософт? Как там написано, вы должны послать сообщение TTM_DELTOOL.

Comment: не удаляет эта команда

Comment: Включите в вопрос код, которым вы пытаетесь удалить.

Comment: Все варианты выводить? Их много

Comment: На мой взгляд должен быть один вариант.:)

Comment: Вы в вопросе это поместите. Напишите, что пробуете удалить таким образом, но не получается. И укажите причину, по которой не получается.

Comment: Я не знаю причины, причина наверно в том, что я не знаю как удалять)

Comment: А проверяли, чему у вас равна переменная I перед вызовом?

Comment: да, это счетчик в цикле, у меня создается 30 подсказок, потом я пытаюсь их всех удалить, но не получается

Comment: Ну, так покажите в своем вопросе второй цикл, как вы удаляете. Нужен минимальный проверяемый пример воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: вместо полного кода хотябы скриншот окна покажите как оно у вас показывает и где

Comment: https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=t2WCO8v5lM5rcbH4mWeYEwhRZhG1fL
После процедуры удаления, объекта нет, а подсказка остается при наведении

Answer (score 0):

Тут работает метод

```
DestroyWindow(ti.hwnd);
```

Вот пример полного кода:

```
void CToolTip::RemoveToolTip() {
    TOOLINFO ti = {0};
    ti.cbSize = sizeof( TOOLINFO );
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
    ti.hwnd   = m_hwndTT;
    ti.uId    = (UINT) m_hwndTT;
    SendMessage( m_hwndTT, TTM_DELTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &ti );
    DestroyWindow( m_hwndTT );
    m_hwndTT = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Мне не tooltip надо удалить, а его элементы

Comment: @helldrg У меня нормально удаляет, ты что-то напутал... не тому посылаешь м.б., `SendMessage(tooltip,...)` - HWND от `HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS,...);` ?

Comment: попробуй у toolTip создать 10 элементов, которые будут всплывать в разных местах и показывать разные значения. У меня не удаляет

Comment: Без полного исходнго кода (включая контекст окружения) Вам вряд-ли помогут, возможно ошбка в другом месте. Надо включить отладочные сообщения, смоделировать ситуацию и посмотреть ответ объета на SendMessage о закрытии. Если Вы взялись программировать, то изучайте вопрос использования отладчиков - без этого не получится.